# Wrapper classes used in class generics

Tags: java, generics

In java, after using a particular **wrapper class** in the **generics of that class**, we can't use that particular wrapper class in any static method or instance method or instance variable of that class. And another problem is the constructor which can only accept Integer object is accepting Strings(or any other wrapper class object) too. Look at the code below,**what is the reason behind these compilation errors?**

```
public class Exp<Integer> {
    Integer val1;

    Integer val2=new Integer(2);//compilation error, cannot instantiate the type Integer

    public Exp(Integer arg1){
        System.out.println(arg1);
        val1=arg1;
    }

    public void lol(){
    //      Integer intValue2=new Integer(2);//compilation error, cannot make static reference to the non static type Integer 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Exp obj1=new Exp(10);
    //      Exp obj2=new Exp("Hello world");

    //      Exp<String> obj3=new Exp<String>("sss");// The constructor takes Integer arg, then why is string arg working perfectly with it?
        String str="10";

        Character c=new Character('c');//works perfectly
        Float f1=3.0f;

        Integer intValue1=new Integer(2); //**compilation error, cannot make static reference to the non static type Integer**

       Exp<Integer> obj4=new Exp<>(10); //**compilation error, cannot make static reference to the non static type Integer**



    }
}
```

Comment: so what's your question about?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker couldn't understand the reason behind the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are not using "wrapper class in the generics", you just named your generic type variable as an existing class in `java.lang` package which hides the original class. However you may still access the original class using fully-qualified name:

```
java.lang.Integer val2 = new java.lang.Integer(2);
```

The same for other places where you have compilation error. In general it's better to avoid such names which clash with `java.lang` classes. Probably you actually wanted to write something different, like

```
public class Exp extends SomeOtherGenericClass<Integer> { ... }
```

Comment: Alright so, that Integer I used is just a variable(not wrapper class), and as @Neil  said I can use any variable there which will act like a placeholder for the actual type to be provided later, mainly at the time of object creation, right?

Answer (score 1):

The type in angle brackets is a dummy which is substituted for the actual type later.  It is common to use `<T>`.  You have used a real type, `<Integer>` which hides the system class `Integer`, so `Integer` in your program is no longer referring to `java.lang.Integer`, leading to the error messages.

Your code should look like this:

```
public class Exp<T> {
    T val1;
    ...
```